# Correct way to substitute variable in an equality

Tags: machine-learning

Help me understand this part in proving a theorem relating to Rademacher complexity. For simplicity, I am going to avoid all extraneous variables ([Eq (4)](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eninamf/ML11/lect1117.pdf)). Random variable $\psi(S)$ is written as $\psi$ for simplicity. Here $S$ is a sample set, $t$ and $\delta$ are small real positive values. $D$ is the data distribution.

Given,
$$Pr[\psi \leq E[\psi] + t] \leq \delta $$

Further, complementing the probability we get

$$Pr[\psi \leq E[\psi] + t]  = 1- Pr[\psi -E[\psi] \geq t]  \leq \delta$$

So, we can write it as

$$ Pr[\psi -E[\psi] \geq t] \geq 1-\delta$$

Finally, we can say that $ \psi\geq t + E[\psi] $ with atleast probability $1-\delta$.

Now, here is the confusing part, the authors are replacing the inequality in another inequality given as

$$ E_D[f] \leq E_S[f] + \psi $$

implies

$$E_D[f] \leq E_S[f] + E[\psi] + t $$
with probability atleast $1-\delta$.

As $\psi$ is larger than $E[\psi] + t$ this substitution doesn't work correct? Where am I going wrong?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the paper that you have linked they assume that
$$
\mathbb{P}\Big( \varphi(S) \ge \mathbb{E}[\varphi(S)] + t\Big) \le \delta
$$
and they prove that such inequality holds iif $t \ge \sqrt{\frac{\log(\delta^{-1})}{m}}$

That implies that, if $t \ge \sqrt{\frac{\log(\delta^{-1})}{m}}$
$$
\mathbb{P}\Big(\varphi(S) \le \mathbb{E}\left[\varphi(S)\right]+t\Big)=1-\mathbb{P}\Big( \varphi(S) \ge \mathbb{E}\left[\varphi(S)\right] + t\Big) \ge 1-\delta
$$
And so you get, with probability at least $1-\delta$
$$\mathbb{E}_D\left[f(z)\right] \le \mathbb{E}_S[f(z)]+\varphi(S) \le  \mathbb{E}_S\left[f(z)\right] +\mathbb{E}\left[\varphi(S)\right]+t$$

Comment: Thank you! I was writing down a wrong inequality in the second step. There is a change in inequality and I totally missed that! I feel stupid :)

Comment: @NarenNallapareddy i literally did the same thing and I had to edit the answer